# Using to + gerund and to + invinitive

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitives, gerunds

"I go to school"
Because 'to' is a preposition then is it correct to write "I go to watching the movie"?

If not, please explain why. Thank you.

Comment: The latter is definitely not correct. I think the problem is that your verb just doesn't match. "I go to school" is fine, as would be "I object to watching the movie." But "I go to watching the movie" is wrong. Maybe someone else can explain why in technical terms.

Comment: It's not enough that ***school*** and ***watching the movie*** are both *nouns*. The "locative" preposition ***to*** requires that it be followed by a referent that you can treat as a (literal or figurative) *location* (or "final state", as in idiomatic *got to pot, go to seed, go to pieces*).

Comment: The preposition 'to' needs a noun phrase / _ing_-phrase with nouniness: I go to school / I go to the cinema /  I went to Leeds / I go to dancing on Thursdays / *I go to dancing in the moonlight. The last example does not work because 'dancing' is not near enough to the noun end of the continuum here. //// 'I went to watch the movie' does not use the preposition; this 'to' is the infinitive marker.  Go + to-infinitive is a well-known catenation.

Comment: They are not equivalent sentences. "I go to school" has one verb. If you want to use two for your second sentence, you should use an infinitive "I go _to watch_  the movies". But this is using "to" in a different way: indicating an infinitive rather than being a preposition. The true equivalent would be "I go to the movies".